# Partial differentiation - total differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Here is a question I have attempted. [image: question]

Could someone let me know if I can treat dv and du as fractions here and cancel, or if this is not the case. Only just began partial differentiation if someone could also tell me if this is correct this would help also. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also check what you have done by taking implicit derivative of $y$

$y=\frac{\ln u}{v} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{du}=\frac{\frac{v}{u}-\ln u \frac{dv}{du}}{v^2}=\frac1{uv}-\frac{\ln u}{v^2}\frac{dv}{du}$

$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac1{uv}-\frac{\ln u}{v^2}\frac{dv}{du} \Rightarrow dy=\frac{1}{uv}du-\frac{\ln u}{v^2}dv$

Also $dy$ could be found by the way that I guess you were trying

$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv$

which comes from chain rule for partial derivatives

Comment: That was the way I was trying yes, which method is simpler in your opinion.

Comment: I think it really depends on how different variables are "distributed" among terms. For example, differentiating $x^2y+(y+1)^3x^4$ might make you have a hard time if you prefer using implicit derivative.